# Unit script AWS/ SED help to add double quotes / how to match double quotes?

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have below records into txt file.

```
000D3A|"RiFR Botnets" AD||83634C|dk
000D3|Ries Bidvest" AD||8364A3C|dhh
000D3A|"Ra Boots D"||83634C|gft
```

here I want to add double quotes for those records which having " into the line using AWK Unix command.

expected output which I want to write to file:

```
000D3A|""RiFR Botnets" AD"||83634C|dk
000D3|"Ries Bidvest" AD"||8364A3C|dhh
000D3A|""Ra Boots""||83634C|gft
```

I have tried using AWS command and AWK -F "|" but how do i search double quotes " here into the every line of file.

Comment: You also probably need to double the existing `"`s inside those fields. Else, since the second field is only affected, try `sed -E 's/(^|\|)([^|]*"[^|]*)($|\|)/\1"\2"\3/' file`

Comment: Please do add your tried code in your question, thank you.

Comment: `""Ries Bidvest" AD"` and `"Ries Bidvest" AD"` and `""Ra Boots""` would break your file by turning it into something that's no longer valid CSV. You probably want some combination of `"Ries Bidvest"" AD"` or ``"""Ries Bidvest"" AD"""` ` and `"Ries Bidvest"" AD"` and then either `"Ra Boots"` or `"""Ra Boots"""` instead.

Comment: This appears to be the same question you asked a few hours earlier at https://stackoverflow.com/q/68383086/1745001 that was closed for not attempting to solve it yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)       # for every field...
        if (match($i,"\""))   # check for "
            $i="\"" $i "\""   # add quotes to that field
    }

    1 # print' file 
000D3A|""RiFR Botnets" AD"||83634C|dk
000D3|"Ries Bidvest" AD"||8364A3C|dhh
000D3A|""Ra Boots D""||83634C|gft
```

Or, you could use this `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/\|([^|]*"[^|]*)\|/|"\1"|/g' file 
# same output
```

(As noted in comments, the result is not valid csv. You requested this, but `"Ries Bidvest" AD"` is not valid quoting and will break csv parsing...)